# Practical usage of new (modifier) functions?

Tags: c#, oop, function, new-operator, modifier

What's the Practical usage of new (modifier) functions?

Comment: I think you are talking about C#. Do rephrase to indicate the language.

Comment: Here's my article on the subject. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's an attempt to work around an aspect of the [fragile base class problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

Answer (score 1):

The new modifier in C# allows you to redefine a method in a subclass hiding the base class method.

I would mainly use it for modifying a non-virtual method in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **new** is when you want a function of the same name, but you don't
want to override. It is identical to the **reintroduce** keyword in Delphi.